# Multiple redirect url with DotNetOpenAuth

Tags: asp.net, redirect, dotnetopenauth

I have a site which can be accessed via different domain names (site1.com, www.site1.com site2.com etc).
When I want to login I specify a redirect URL, this redirect URL should match any of the possible redirect URL's in the database.

I am using DotNetOpenAuth (oauth2) in asp.net. However I am unable to let a Client Request match this list of allowed redirect as I can only pass 1 redirect as a valid url.

```
return new ClientDescription(apiSecret, redirectUri, ClientType.Confidential);
```

Does anybody have a suggestion how to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am looking at one of our OAuth2 servers implemented with DotNetOpenAuth 4.3.4 and it seems that the server expects us to implement

```
public IClientDescription GetClient( string clientIdentifier )
```

which means the server expects an abstraction rather than a concrete type.

The actual implementation we have is a custom class

```
public class CustomClientDescription : IClientDescription
```

that has a method to validate the callback url

```
public bool IsCallbackAllowed( Uri callback )
```

This is where your custom implementation could match the callback url to a **list** of possible uris rather than a single uri.